# Can't find bundle in Java web start

Tags: java, applet, bundle, java-web-start

I Have an Applet application and I am migrating this to JWS. When I Run it in a browser (Applet), it's fine and I made the JNLP file to download the application to the local machine. When I put the jnlp file in some folder that doesn't contain the 'international.properties' files it doens't work, but if I put this in the same folder it works, we have other application that does the same thing and it works. I can't really find the error. Is there anything related to cache? Is there a way to put international.properties in cache?

The error is:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name     international, locale pt_BR
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at teste.applet.testeMainPanel.initComponents(testeMainPanel.java:687)
    at teste.applet.testeMainPanel.<init>(testeMainPanel.java:62)
    at teste.applet.testeApplication.initMainPanel(testeApplication.java:183)
    at teste.applet.testeLoginPanel.jButton1ActionPerformed(testeLoginPanel.java:104)
    at teste.applet.testeLoginPanel.access$000(testeLoginPanel.java:12)
    at teste.applet.testeLoginPanel$1.actionPerformed(testeLoginPanel.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at teste.applet.testeMainFrame.<init>(testeMainFrame.java:21)
    at teste.applet.testeApplication.initMainFrame(testeApplication.java:167)
    at     teste.applet.testeLoginPanel.jButton1ActionPerformed(testeLoginPanel.java:105)
    at teste.applet.testeLoginPanel.access$000(testeLoginPanel.java:12)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     teste.applet.testeApplication.initMainFrame(testeApplication.java:177)
    at                 teste.applet.testeLoginPanel.jButton1ActionPerformed(testeLoginPanel.java:105)
    at teste.applet.testeLoginPanel.access$000(testeLoginPanel.java:12)
    at     teste.applet.testeLoginPanel$1.actionPerformed(testeLoginPanel.java:81)
```

The JNLP file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://path/teste/" href="teste.jnlp">
<information>
<title>TesteDesktop</title>
<vendor>FACTORY</vendor>
<homepage href="www.factory.com.br"/>
<description>TESTE WebStart</description>
<icon kind="shortcut" href="imagens/teste.ico"/>
<icon href="imagens/splash_screen_teste.png" kind="splash"/>
<shortcut online="true">
<desktop/>
<menu submenu="TESTE"/>
</shortcut>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions />
</security>
<application-desc main-class="teste.applet.testeApplication">
<argument>http://path/teste/</argument>
<argument>PORTUGUESE</argument>
<argument>F</argument>
</application-desc>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.6+"/>
<jar eager="true" href="teste.jar" main="true"/>
</resources>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).